# Why does std::accumulate generate 705032704 as output instead of the sum of the elements in the vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, overflow, accumulate

The output is 705032704 instead of 5000000000. Why is that? I thought `std::accumulate` would compute the sum of the elements in the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <numeric>

typedef long long ll;

int main()
{

    std::vector<ll> nums = {1000000000, 1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);
    std::cin.ignore();

}
```

Comment: My first guess would also be an overflow. Simply check this hypothesis with smaller numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard algorithm `std::accumulate` is declared the following way

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
T accumulate(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T init);
```

So the template parameter `T` is used as the type of the accumulator.

In this call

```
std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0)
```

the deduced type of the parameter T is `int` because the integer literal `0` has the type `int`. As a result there is an overflow of the sum stored in the accumulator of the type `int`.

You have to use at least the long long integer literal `0ll` as

`std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0ll`)

or maybe it is reasonable to use a double floating literal

```
std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0.0 )
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

using ll = long long int;

int main()
{
    std::vector<ll> nums = {1000000000, 1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000};
    std::cout << std::accumulate( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 0ll ) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::accumulate( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 0.0 ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
5000000000
5e+09
```

Comment: Why isn't OP's code throwing an overflow exception?  `int` is signed.

Comment: @Spencer Neither the algorithm nor the operation throws an exception.

Comment: @Spencer -- overflow of a signed integer type produces undefined behavior. That could involve throwing an exception, but that's not required and not at all common.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's good to know. To me, this means  the standard explanation for avoiding unsigned integer types (silent wrapping) doesn't hold water.

Comment: @Spencer -- despite the undefinedness, the behavior of signed overflow is typically benign. It's whatever the processor does, which typically means wrapping to the smallest value of the type. But that's not guaranteed, of course.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, as proved by OP's experience. I was compelled to comment because the (to me) bad advice against unsigned integers is a pet peeve.

Comment: Can you use the `0ull` literal instead of `0ll`? They are all non-negative.

Comment: @ElProfesor It can be used provided that all elements of the vector are non-negative.

Answer (score 8):

Integer overflow.

[`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) infers the type of summing variable from the type of third argument. Since you pass in an integer, the result of `std::accumulate` will also be an integer.

Pass `long long` literal instead (from C++11):

```
std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0LL);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't sum into a `long long` but in a `int`, try this

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{

    std::vector<ll> nums = {1000000000, 1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000};
    std::cout << std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0ll);
    std::cin.ignore();

}
```

Comment: Just write `0ll`?